# Conexão com BD via php retornando json ao javascript

Tags: php, javascript, json

Galera estou tentando uma conexão com o bd via php e retornando um json para o meu javascript, mas tem algo que eu estou esquecendo ou fazendo errado, pois já tentei fazer de várias maneiras mas nunca retorna o valor do banco, sempre da um erro em algum "trycatch" no meio do caminho.

Esses arquivos estão todos no mesmo servidor.

Caso queira ver o código rodando:

http://engenini.com.br/tst/

Meu Código:

```js
/**
* Capturar itens do banco de dados
*/
function carregarItens(){
 //variáveis
 var itens = "", url = "dados.php";

    //Capturar Dados Usando Método AJAX do jQuery
    $.ajax({
     url: $url,
     cache: false,
     dataType: "json",
     beforeSend: function() {
      $("h2").html("Carregando..."); //Carregando
     },
     error: function() {
      $("h2").html("Há algum problema com a fonte de dados");
     },
     success: function(retorno) {
      if(retorno[0].erro){
       $("h2").html(retorno[0].erro);
      }
      else{
       //Laço para criar linhas da tabela
       for(var i = 0; i<retorno.length; i++){
        itens += "<tr>";
        itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].id + "</td>";
        itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].nome + "</td>";
        itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].console + "</td>";
        itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].preco + "</td>";
        itens += "</tr>";
       }
       //Preencher a Tabela
       $("#minhaTabela tbody").html(itens);
       
       //Limpar Status de Carregando
       $("h2").html("Carregado");
      }
     }
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <!--  <link rel="icon" type="favicon.png" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css"> -->
 
 <!--jQuery-->
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!--Script-->
 <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 
 
</head>
<body onload="carregarItens()">
 <section>
  <h1>PortilloDesign Tutorial JSON + PHP</h1>
  <!--Área que mostrará carregando-->
  <h2></h2>
  <!--Tabela-->
  <table id="minhaTabela">
   <caption>Cadastro de Jogos</caption>
   <thead>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Jogo</th>
    <th>Console</th>
    <th>Valor</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
  </table>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<?php
/**
* Tutorial jSON
*/

//Definir formato de arquivo
header('Content-Type:' . "text/plain");


$username = ''; // 
$password = '';
$hostname = '';  //
$database = '';
//$porta = '' // 

$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
 or die("Não é possível conectar ao MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db($database,$con) 
  or die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados");



//@pg_close($con); //Encerrrar Conexão

if(!$con) {
 echo '[{"erro": "Não foi possível conectar ao banco"';
 echo '}]';
}else {
 //SQL de BUSCA LISTAGEM
 $sql  = "SELECT * FROM jogos ORDER BY console";
 $result = pg_query($sql); //Executar a SQL
 $n   = pg_num_rows($result); //Número de Linhas retornadas

 if (!$result) {
  //Caso não haja retorno
  echo '[{"erro": "Há algum erro com a busca. Não retorna resultados"';
  echo '}]';
 }else if($n<1) {
  //Caso não tenha nenhum item
  echo '[{"erro": "Não há nenhum dado cadastrado"';
  echo '}]';
 }else {
  //Mesclar resultados em um array
  for($i = 0; $i<$n; $i++) {
   $dados[] = pg_fetch_assoc($result, $i);
  }
  
  echo json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 }
}
?>
```

Comment: consegues por aqui o output de `json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)` ?

Comment: Qual é o erro, onde para?

Comment: @MoshMage http://engenini.com.br/tst/dados/dados.php

O erro está no php, pois era para aparecer o json na saida.

Comment: @rray ele para aqui: "error: function() {
      $("h2").html("Há algum problema com a fonte de dados");"  no js, mas no php ele não está retornando nada.

Comment: Da um console.log no `retorno` isso já ajuda identificar o que aconteceu

Comment: De onde vem a variável `$con` ? E porque usar `mysql` ?

Comment: @rray o console.log no "retorno" não retorna nada.

Comment: @edilson, foi erro na hora de colocar o código aqui, dbhandle é o con (Vou editar)

Comment: A url no ajax está '$url', mas você definiu apenas a variavel 'url'.

Comment: Amigo é meio complicado tentar entender o código, porque vejo demasiadas irregularidades e variáveis que nem sequer foram definidas para além da variável `$con` existem várias outras. Digo então, que se o erro estiver no `PHP` deve ser uma das linhas de conexão que fazem uso da função `die()`.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Sim, eu concertei isso.

Comment: @Edilson o código está bastante estranho, mas aconteceu por eu não ter conseguido a conexão e dai eu fui pegando outros códigos pela internet que não eram meus. Acredito eu se seja simples, não sou bom ainda com web, mas oque tiver de errado no seu ponto de vista pode falar que eu procuro saber e arrumo.

Comment: @Edilson Eu retirei os códigos or die, e agora ele da erro de conexão.

Comment: De onde pegaste este tutorial ?

Comment: @Edilson Peguei [aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9x47niEJk_M)

Comment: Amigo, editei a tua resposta e coloquei um exemplo totalmente funcional que eu mesmo criei e testei à partir do tutorial original.

Comment: @Edilson Desculpe a ignorância, mas onde está o código que você editou? Se puder colocar como resposta acho que seria melhor.

Comment: Ah pois, parece que recusaram a minha edição, vou criar uma nova resposta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá, este código aqui funcionou.

## Tabela SQL

```
--
-- Estrutura da tabela `jogos`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jogos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
  `console` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `preco` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `nome` (`nome`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Extraindo dados da tabela `jogos`
--

INSERT INTO `jogos` (`id`, `nome`, `console`, `preco`) VALUES
(1, 'Resident Evil - Retaliacao', 'XBOX 360', '3000.00'),
(2, 'The Elders Scrolls - Skyrim', 'XBOX 360', '5000.00');
```

## Ficheiro HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>JSON + PHP</title>
        <!-- biblioteca jQuery !-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <!-- Script externo !-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body onload="carregarItens()">
        <section>
            <h1>JSON+ PHP</h1>

            <h2></h2>

            <table id="tabela">
                <caption>Cadastro</caption>
                <thead>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Jogo</th>
                    <th>Console</th>
                    <th>Preço</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

## Script jQuery

```
function carregarItens(){
    // variavel itens(vazia), e a variavel url(o ficheiro php)
    var itens, url = "json.php";

    //Chamada Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: url, 
        cache: false, 
        dataType: "json", 
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("h2").html("Carregando...");  
        },
        error: function(errori){
            $("h2").html("Erro, dados não carregados"); 
        },
        success: function(retorno){
            if(retorno[0].erro){
                $("h2").html(retorno[0].erro);
            } else {
                for(var i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++){
                    itens += "<tr>";
                    itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].id + "</td>";
                    itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].nome + "</td>";
                    itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].console + "</td>";
                    itens += "<td>" + retorno[i].preco + "</td>";
                    itens += "<tr>";
                }
                //Colocar os valores da variavel itens no tbody da tabela
                //$("#tabela tbody").html(itens);
                //Mudar status "Carregando" e fazer desaparecer, usei a função fadeOut com um callback
                $("h2").html("Carregado").fadeOut(function(){$("#tabela tbody").html(itens);}, 500);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

## Ficheiro PHP[v2]

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario_", "senha_", "banco_de_dados");

if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    // Erros como este normalmente nem são visualizados pelo usuário, por segurança
    die('[{"erro" : "Não foi possivel conectar com o banco de dados !"}]');
    // À partir daqui, o código só é executado se a conexão for feita com sucesso !
}

$sql = mysqli_query($conexao, "SELECT * FROM jogos");
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) >= 1){ 
    //Looping com o while   
    // O looping é feito apenas, se existirem dados da tabela
    while(false != ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))){
        $dados[] = $resultado;
    }
    //Aqui codificamos o conjunto de valores para um formato JSON
    echo json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    mysqli_free_result($sql);
} else {
    //Caso o numero de resultados seja  menor que 1 (0), termina a execução
    // E mostra essa mensagem de erro, num formato JSON;    
    die('[{"erro" : "Não foi possivel conectar ao banco de dados !"}]');
}
mysqli_close($conexao); 

// Versão original do script PHP
// header("Content-Type: text/plain");

// $conexao = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario_", "senha_", "banco_de_dados");

// if(!$conexao){
    // echo '[{"erro" : "Não foi possivel conectar ao banco"}]';
// } else {
    // $sql = "SELECT * FROM jogos";
    // $resultado = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    // $rows = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
    // $dados = "";
    // $i = 0;
    // if(!$resultado){
        // echo '[{"erro" : "Consulta falhou"}]';
    // } elseif($rows <= 0){
        // echo '[{"erro" : "Nenhum resultado"}]';
    // } else {
        // for($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++){
            // $dados[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
        // }
        // echo json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    // }
// } 

?>
```

Segui o tutorial que indicaste, e funcionou. Acho que o problema estava na conexão com o banco de dados, ou então, durante a conversão dos valores retornados, para o formato JSON, porque eu estava a introduzir os valores no banco de dados manualmente, utilizando caracteres Unicode sem antes sanear.

## Exemplo:

Nesse insert o nome do jogo não está acentuado porque vou introduzir ele diretamente no banco de dados, sem quaisquer tratamento dos valores a serem inseridos.

> (1, 'Resident Evil - Retaliacao', 'XBOX 360', '3000.00')

Agora se eu fosse introduzir ele, via formulário , eu iria antes preparar ele para introduzir no banco de dados, mesmo com os acentos. O que iria resultar de uma conversão dos acentos em valores hexadecimais que seriam introduzidos no banco de dados, e que quando fossem processados pelo servidor, teriam o mesmo retorno, porém, sem retornar erro.

> ...
>
> $nome_do_produto = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexao,$_POST["nome_do_produto"]);
>
> ...

Fiz também os possíveis para deixar o código o mais parecido possível com o que estava no tutorial, sendo que alterei apenas algumas coisas. Muitas coisas poderiam ainda ser melhoradas nesse tutorial, mas algumas não fazem tanta diferença.

Se ainda restarem dúvidas, consulte a página do [PHP.net](http://php.net). Ou então vai pesquisando no `Google`, ou mesmo aqui no `ptstackoverflow`.

Peço desculpas, se haver demasiados erros ortográficos, não tive muito tempo para fazer a leitura.

Boa sorte, e até mais !

Comment: Que isso Edilson, eu que lhe agradeço, consegui aqui era algum problema no BD e nos códigos do Postgre que tinham o "pg_", e eu não tinha alterado. Mas só não sei a diferença de usar o MySQL ou o mysqli, tenho um pouco de dúvida com isso, mas o resto eu entendi legal, consegui evoluir bastante, valeu.

Comment: Olá novamente, a diferença é simples, o `MySQLi` é bem mais seguro, e o `MySQL` para além de ser menos seguro, foi desapreciado. Por essa mesma razão eu deixo sempre uma referência da página do [PHP.net](http://php.net) no final das respostas relacionadas com o php.

Answer (score 2):

Refiz o código do JS, mas preciso arrumar a conexão, fiz algumas mudanças mas ele retorna isso no php:

```
[{"erro": "HÃ¡ algum erro com a busca. NÃ£o retorna resultados"}]
```

Será que foi alguma coisa na criação da tabela? Código da tabela:

```
SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET time_zone = "+00:00";



CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `jogos` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `console` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `preco` int(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;


INSERT INTO `jogos` (`id`, `nome`, `console`, `preco`) VALUES
(1, 'Geo', 'xbox', '20'),
(2, 'Pett', 'ps3', '50'),
(3, 'Ame', 'xbox', '100');
```

Código php(atual):

```
<?php
/**
* Tutorial jSON
*/

//Definir formato de arquivo
header('Content-Type:' . "text/plain");

$username = ''; // Se for servidor compartilhado, deve vir com algo_
$password = '';
$hostname = '';  // Pode ser que seja um IP ou um endereço
$database = '';
//$porta = '3333' // As vezes pode ser necessário passar a porta, geralmente não é.

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database)
 or die("Não é possível conectar ao MySQL");

//$selected = mysql_select_db($database,$dbhandle) 
//  or die("Não foi possível conectar ao banco de dados");

//@pg_close($con); //Encerrrar Conexão

if(!$dbhandle) {
    echo '[{"erro": "Não foi possível conectar ao banco"}]';
}else {
    //SQL de BUSCA LISTAGEM
    //$sql  = "SELECT * FROM jogos ORDER BY console";
    //$sql  = "SELECT id, nome, console, preco FROM jogos";
    $sql    = "SELECT * FROM jogos ORDER BY console";
    //$result = mysqli_query($dbhandle, $sql);//Executar a SQL
    $result = mysqli_query($sql);//Executar a SQL
    $n      = mysqli_num_rows($result); //Número de Linhas retornadas

    if (!$result) {
        //Caso não haja retorno
        echo '[{"erro": "Há algum erro com a busca. Não retorna resultados"}]';
    }else if($n<1) {
        //Caso não tenha nenhum item
        echo '[{"erro": "Não há nenhum dado cadastrado"}]';
    }else {
        //Mesclar resultados em um array
        for($i = 0; $i<$n; $i++) {
            $dados[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result, $i);
        }

        echo json_encode($dados, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    }
}
?>
```

Valeu ai quem ajudou e desculpe a ignorância sobre o assunto, hehehe.